# WooCommerce Cart Items

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have this lovely script that presents the user with the number of items in their cart but not the number of products...

```
 <?php echo sprintf (_n( '%d item', '%d',count( WC()->cart->get_cart())),count( WC()->cart->get_cart())); ?>
```

One issue that I am having is that when there is 1 item in cart it says "1 item", when there are more than 1 item it gives me simply a number "2".

How can I remove the word Item when there is only one item in the cart.

All help is appreciated.

Rob

Answer (score 1):

You're passing two parameters to `_n` function, the first one is the pattern for one item, and the second for 2 or more. Just change the pattern.

Show only numbers:

```
<?php echo sprintf (_n( '%d', '%d',count( WC()->cart->get_cart())),count( WC()->cart->get_cart())); ?>
```

Show `item` for two or more:

```
<?php echo sprintf (_n( '%d', '%d items',count( WC()->cart->get_cart())),count( WC()->cart->get_cart())); ?>
```

For more information check [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_n).

But, if you want to show only the number, you could echo the cart count directly:

`echo count( WC()->cart->get_cart());`

or

`echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();`